# adding exported parts to an exisiting MEF container

Tags: .net, mef

Is there a way to add exported parts from a catalog to an existing MEF CompositionContainer? I'm aware of ComposeExportedValue extension method, but what if I wanted to add a whole DirectoryCatalog to the list of exports? I don't need recomposition in this case, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [DirectoryCatalog.Refresh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.directorycatalog.refresh.aspx) to pick up new assemblies in a folder. To add entirely new catalogs, you could pass an [AggregateCatalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.aggregatecatalog.aspx) to the container and then call `.Add` on [AggregateCatalog.Catalogs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.aggregatecatalog.catalogs.aspx).

Comment: I'm surprised I overlooked this. Thanks a lot.